# How to enable/ disable element by clicking on the sprite element in three.js

Tags: three.js, raycasting

I have three sprites in the group `groupIcons.add(icon1, icon2, icon3);` and three planes in another group `groupPhotos.add(photo1, photo2, photo3);`. These groups are THREE.group objects.
The goal is if `icon1` is clicked to perform `scene.add(photo1)`, if `icon2` is clicked to perform `scene.add(photo2)`.
I found many documentations on how to change colors or to drag objects but not the solution to my problem.
I would appreciate any suggestion.
My code is down below.

```js
const groupIcons = new THREE.Group();
groupIcons.add(icon1, icon2, icon3);
scene.add( groupIcons);

const groupPhotos = new THREE.Group();
groupPhotos.add(photo1, photo2, photo3);

// Then I want something like this
raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
pointer = new THREE.Vector2();

window.addEventListener('click', clickIcons);
function clickIcons(event) {
    pointer.set((event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1, - (event.clientY /   window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1);
    raycaster.setFromCamera( pointer, camera );
    const intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( groupIcons, true);

    if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {

       // if (ray intersects icon1) {
       //   scene.add(photo1)
       // if (ray intersects icon2) {
       //   scene.add(photo2)
       // and so on
       
       // I also want to hide photos elements when these icons are clicked (something like toggle)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://threejs.org/docs/?q=Object#api/en/core/Object3D.visible
Sprite has an `visible` property.

```
sprite.visible = false;
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/mqtvjzsr/2/

Comment: Thank you @zalupa_konya . Unfortunately, I'm still not getting desired results.
I inserted the following code in my script and all what I got from this is when I click anywhere in the scene, icon1 becomes invisible. I checked on the internet and seems the ray doesn't detect the sprites objects... 
 ` const intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children);
    for (let i = 0; i < intersects.length; i++) {
        intersects[i].object.visible = !intersects[i].object.visible;
        icon1.visible = false;
    }`

Comment: @ivka No it does. https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/Sprite.raycast 
Play with example above, it works.